# Não conseguido abrir meu server pelo node.js

Tags: node.js, express.js

Hoje tive meu primeiro contato com node.js e a sequência da video aula foi assim:

```
npm init -y // no terminal do visual studio (Criou o package.json que nem na vídeo aula)
```

```
npm install express // no terminal (Criou as pastas do express e o package-lock.json e apareceu a dependência no package.json)
```

Ai o professor falou que ia iniciar o servidor então foi feito um arquivo `server.js` com o comando

```
require('express')().listen(5500)
```

Ai no terminal foi feito o comando que não consegui realizar

```
node src/server.js
```

Ele deveria aparecer um lance de permissão do `node.js` e me permitir abrir o servidor mas não Vai de jeito nenhum! Ninguém que eu conheço conhece `node.js`, alguma de vocês sabe o que eu fiz?

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem a questão da permissão que você mencionou.

A única coisa feita em seu código foi instanciar um servidor que rodaria na porta 5500 - http://localhost:5500/. Porém como vc não possui nenhuma rota, ao acessar este endereço deveria receber `Cannot GET /`.

Voltando ao seu problema, ao rodar o `node src/server.js` você estava na pasta raiz ? se você estiver na pasta src, você deve rodar apenas `node server.js`. Este comando não vai retornar nada em seu terminal, o terminal vai ficar congelado pois ele estará processando o servidor na porta mencionada.

Pra você ter isso acontecendo de uma forma mais "visual", mude seu arquivo `server.js` para isso:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(5500, () => {
  console.log(`O servidor está rodando na porta 5500`)
})
```

`const express = require('express')` e `const app = express()` estamos declarando que a variável app será uma instância do express.

`app.get('/' ...` Estamos informando que ao bater na raiz do nosso servidor (a /), será retornado apenas um texto escrito "Hello World". Conforme avançar no estudo você vai entender melhor o que são `req`, `res`, `res.send`, etc.

e por fim em `app.listen(5500, ...` estamos informando que vamos rodar o servidor na porta 5500, com um callback que irá printar no terminal a informação `O servidor está rodando na porta 5500`.

Lembre se de rodar `node src/server.js` caso esteja na pasta raiz ou `node server.js` se estiver na pasta `src`.